# C#: How to specify default parameter value, for container type?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, containers, default

E.g, I've got a member function like this:

```
void f(List<int> listInt)...
```

Can I specify a default value for this listInt? Seems I cannot directly give it a "new" value as compiler requires a compile time constant for default values.

How to achieve that?

Thanks a lot.

---

Note I'm using Vs2017 and dotnet core 2.0, while this thread [C#-How to use empty List as optional parameter] is too old and the solution no longer works.

Comment: According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), this cannot be done, although you can easily bypass the problem as explained in the duplicate answers

Comment: I reopened the question, but according to my test with LInqPAD6 (Net Core version 3.1) it works as expected using the default(List) approach

Comment: The only default value you can use in the signature for `List<int>` is `null`. Inside the method you can replace `null` with whatever you want, but in the signature you only have one option.

Comment: @Steve Why was the question reopened? The duplicate in the edit history is the only option and answers this question perfectly. Was there some confusion about what the issue is?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The OP added the info about using VS2017 and net core 2.0. I am not able to test if something different in that configuration (I strongly doubt about it). Cannot close again now.